# XCTest Results Not Published in Azure DevOps Despite Successful Test Execution

Tags: ios, xcode, azure, unit-testing, pipeline

I am encountering an issue with XCTest results not being published in Azure DevOps after successful test execution. The XCTest case runs for iOS in Xcode, and the tests pass successfully. However, when attempting to publish the results in Azure DevOps, the JUnit file appears to be empty.

It seems like the JUnit file is being generated, but the results are not being picked up by Azure DevOps in the JUnit.

Here is a snippet of the log:

**Test result is stored in build/reports/junit.xml**

```
Run Attachments will be stored in LogStore
[debug]Object of TestRunPublisher created.
[debug]Object of TestLogStore created.
[debug]Object of JUnitResultParser created.
[debug]Entering ParseTestResultFiles
[debug]runContext.ReleaseURI is null
[debug]runContext.ReleaseEnvironmentUri is null
**[debug]Reading test results from file '/Users/runner/work/1/s/build/reports/junit.xml'.
[debug]Total test results: 0.**
No Result Found to Publish '/Users/runner/work/1/s/build/reports/junit.xml'.
[debug]Leaving ParseTestResultFiles
```

I have followed the usual steps for configuring test reporting in the pipeline YAML file, and the path to the JUnit file is correct.

Here is an excerpt from the YAML file:

```
 steps:
- task: Xcode@5
  displayName: 'Run XCTest'
  inputs:
    actions: test
    configuration: Debug
    sdk: iphonesimulator
    xcWorkspacePath: '**/MYscheme.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace'
    scheme: MYscheme
signingOption: auto
    teamId:XXXXX
    destinationPlatformOption: custom
    destinationPlatform: iOS
    destinationSimulators: 'iPhone 13 Pro'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testRunTitle: TestResults

steps:
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  displayName: 'Publish Pipeline Artifact'
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/build/reports/'
    artifact: JUnitResults


I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on why the test results might not be getting picked up and published in Azure DevOps despite the successful XCTest execution. Thank you in advance for your assistance!
```